# How to Assert or Verify Multiple Required Error message at the time on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Problem Description:**

I want to verify a Blank Input field Required `Error` message should be displayed or not. Example like that.
I have `Web Element`

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="red-text text-darken-4 fs-0--8">First Name is required</div>
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="red-text text-darken-4 fs-0--8">Last Name is required</div>
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="red-text text-darken-4 fs-0--8">Phone Name is required</div>
```

These `Error` message I want to verify at the time all message `assert` or not.

Can you please help me how to `assert` all error message at the time using `selenium web driver`.

Comment: can you please explain in details i didn't get exactly what you want to do, you want to verify it on UI side on web page or directly from HTML DOM ?

Comment: HTML web page UI design

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'First Name is required')]")).isDisplayed()`; have you tried something like this? Repeat it number of times you want it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test all assert at once then you have to add softAssert in your code this will give you final results after check all the fields.
If not when assert failed happens (Assume First name error is invalid) system will throw assertion error after it.

```
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        String ActualErrorMEssage = firstNameerrorXpath.getText;
        String ActualErrorMEssage2 = secondNameNameerrorXpath.getText;
        softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
        softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage2,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
        softAssert.assertAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can see all the error messages, when you don't enter anything into the text boxes and click on submit or register, you can get text of all this error messages and assert them.
But, if your website functionality is like let's say when you don't enter anything it shows only error for the first name field and all the other UI error's are not being shown, then you can't verify all the error messages at a time.

If all the error messages are shown at once, you can take them into a arraylist and by using Assert.assertEquals(expectedArray,actualArray), you can assert everything at once.